# How to select tables that have different columns except for an id

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running MySQL 5.1.61 and my MyISAM tables are set up as

```
objects:
id | owner | created_date
---------------------------------
1  | xxx   | xxxxxxxx
2  | xxx   | xxxxxxxx

photos:
id | width | height | url
-------------------------
2  | 800   | 480    | http://somewhere.com/photo.jpeg

posts:
id | message
------------
1  | Hello, world!
2  | Goodbye!
```

I want something like

```
SELECT * FROM objects LEFT JOIN posts ON objects.id=posts.id LEFT JOIN photos ON objects.id=photos.id
```

but running this query gives me

```
id | owner | created_date | id | message | id   | width | height | url
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | xxx   | xxxxxxxx     | 1  | Hell... | NULL | NULL  | NULL   | NULL
2  | xxx   | xxxxxxxx     | 2  | Good... | 2    | 800   | 480    | http://som....
```

Which is what I want, except for the duplicate id columns.

Short of spelling out all the columns I want which would be tedious but one time only, how can I get rid of those duplicate id columns?  I only want one column since they're all going to have the same value anyway.

Also note that I may add more tables, such as 'video', 'url', so its not just these two tables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Short of spelling out all the columns I want which would be tedious but one time only, how can I get rid of those duplicate id columns?

You **should** spell out the columns explicitly.

You can do what you want with `USING`, but I'd still advise against using `SELECT *`:

```
SELECT *
FROM objects
LEFT JOIN posts USING (id)
LEFT JOIN photos USING (id)
```

Result:

```
ID  OWNER   CREATED_DATE    MESSAGE         WIDTH   HEIGHT  URL
1   xxx     xxxxxxxx        Hello, world!   (null)  (null)  (null)
2   xxx     xxxxxxxx        Goodbye!        800     480     http://somewhere.com/photo.jpeg
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87acb/1)

Comment: I'm still prototyping things so I was looking for a "dirty" solution and USING is exactly what I was looking for.  In production, I absolutely agree I'll specify each column I want.

Comment: I'd add a note, that if other columns' names are not distinguish, remember to add a table name or an alias, like: `SELECT t1.id, t1.col1, t2.col1 FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ...`.